# Windows 7, Android studio, finding drivers for Nexus 7

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, nexus-7

I'm going to ask a "duplicate" question -- except that the solutions haven't worked for me.   I am trying to use my Nexus 7 with Android Studio to debug my app.
http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html   tells me for Windows 7 to  get drivers & download them. http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver had more specifics;  Done.  I checked that it's debuggable, "true" in build.gradle.

[Android Studio wont recognize Nexus 7 as device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615319/android-studio-wont-recognize-nexus-7-as-device) says I should connect my Nexus 7 as a camera -- it is.  I've tried it as a media device, as well.

[Android Studio wont recognize Nexus 7 as device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615319/android-studio-wont-recognize-nexus-7-as-device)  says that I need to go to the device in the device manager and ask it to "update the drivers."   It tells me they're all there and updated.

Under "Android SDK" it says that "Google USB Driver, rev. 11" is installed.

I've gone through several different paths to install the drivers but Android Studio doesn't seem to be able to find them.

I just bought the Nexus 7 hoping it was a better match for Android Studio than my Galaxy Tab...  but seems not.

Is this the part where I  install Android Studio again? (I can't get my Windows 8 computer to find it, either, but the Galaxy usually works on that.   Exactly the same thing happens.)

(Oh, and yes, I've done the "knock 7 times" on the button to "become a developer," too, and installed and reinstalled the drivers from the SDK manager.)

Comment: Update:   getting exactly same thing on third computer with Windows 7.   Does anyone know how to get Android Studio to find the right drivers?

Comment: Update:   I've gone into the device settings and looked for *anything* I could change that might change this.   (Since 3 different computers won't recognize the device, I'm thinking that the device has the problem.)   The computers find the device, but Android Studio doesn't, even though it tells me (and I've uninstalled and reinstalled several times from the SDK manager) that the USB driver is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I combed more previous similar questions and found one that referred to this: http://www.theandroidsoul.com/nexus-7-2013-drivers-installation-guide-43183/ and the "troubleshooting" got me to the full download; I then had to use [Selected Device Incompatible - Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352368/selected-device-incompatible-android-studio) and I'm back at developing :)